# Using nix in a continuous delivery workflow

Tags: continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, nix, semaphore-ci

Can `nix` be used in a continuous-delivery workflow?

We're using [semaphore](http://semaphoreci.com/) as our continuous integration service, and now I'm looking into building packages upon a successful build. For this I'm considering using `nix`.

I don't know what would be the right way of setting up a continuous delivery pipeline with this package manager. It seems that such an automated process would involve:

1. Making a branch of the [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/) repository (in the CI server).
2. Updating the `rev` field of `fetchFromGithub`.
3. (automatically) submitting a pull-request.

But I don't know if this makes sense, and also I'm concerned that the continuous-delivery process involved a manual step (having an human aproving the pull-request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can nix be used in a continuous-delivery workflow?

Yes. It's typically done with [Hydra](https://nixos.org/hydra/), a CI system built with Nix. But, it *may* be possible to do this with Semaphore.

Semaphore CI provides build environments that are language specific, but... it's [running Ubuntu](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/supported-stack.html), so theoretically you can do something like this:

1. Install [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) as if it were a dependency. See [this](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/how-to-install-dependency.html) article.
2. Add your Nix package, which I suppose you can do with Git. You don't really need to clone Nixpkgs.
3. Use `nix-build` to build your package. This will create a `result` symbolic link to the build output.
4. Deploy using [git-deploy](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/deploying-with-git-deploy.html).

If you do something like this with your package you can call it directly from `nix-build` because you won't have to provide the package dependencies as arguments:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
   stdenv = pkgs.stdenv;
   ...
in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
    ..
  }
```

### Optimization

Installing Nix for every build is wasteful, but perhaps you can cache the Nix store. See [this](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/caching-between-builds.html) article.

Comment: Great. One question though. Where would you publish the resulting package to? I would like the built package to be available to anybody who uses nix.

Comment: Ah.... well, packages are added to the Nix Packages Collection by submitting a pull request, which triggers Hydra to build it. In fact, you'll see the build status in the pull request. Then reviewers will take at a look at it and approve it, or not. So yes, pull request approval is manual. Side note, the commits are expected to be on the master branch.

Comment: How exactly does Hydra handle continuous delivery? All it does is run `nix-build` and a web interface to view build logs.